# Limit of Composition of Functions from Graph

Tags: calculus, limits

I had the following question on an exam but I have not come to terms with the solution.

> What is $\lim_{x \to 0} f(1-x^2)$?

[image: limitq]

I found the solution to be that the limit does not exist since $f$ is not continuous but the solution was $3$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that you are missing the fact that, when $x$ is close to $0$, $1-x^2$ is close to *and smaller than* $1$. So, yes, the answer *is* $3$.